# Was the location of the portal to Landover in "Magic Kingdom for Sale — SOLD!" an actual site in Virginia?

Tags: real-location, terry-brooks, landover-series

Re-reading Terry Brooks' 1986 fantasy novel "Magic Kingdom for Sale — SOLD!", there's a passage on page 49 describing how the protagonist, Ben Holiday, is to find the access point to the magical kingdom of Landover:

> The map supplied by Meeks lay open on the seat beside him. He had memorized the instructions written on it. He was to follow 64 west almost to Waynesboro and exit the Skyline Drive on the road south toward Lynchburg. Twenty miles in, he would come upon a wayside turn-around on a promontory overlooking a stretch of mountains and valleys within the George Washington National Forest. It would be marked with a small green sign with the number 13 in black. There would be a courtesy phone and a weather shelter. He was to pull over, park, and lock the car with the keys inside, and cross the roadway to the nature path on the opposite side. He was to follow the path into the mountains for approximately two miles. At that point, he would be met.

Was Terry Brooks inspired by an actual location along the Blue Ridge Parkway in Virginia when he wrote this very specific description of the "portal" site leading to Landover?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### Yes, this does describe a real place.

<sup>*with a big thank you to **S. Fruggiero** for help in finding it!*</sup>

**TL;DR**: [here](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir/CHARLOTTESVILLE+airport,+Bowen+Loop,+Charlottesville,+VA,+United+States/37.9073362,-78.979051/@38.0047898,-78.9942638,76767m/am=t/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m8!4m7!1m5!1m1!1s0x89b47713acdd4c67:0xc4ddf2ed660969f5!2m2!1d-78.4516095!2d38.1392317!1m0) is a link to Google Maps directions to the exact spot from Charlottesville Airport.

> He was to follow 64 west almost to Waynesboro and exit the Skyline Drive on the road south toward Lynchburg.

This is somewhat confusing. The 64 is an east-to-west road, but the Skyline Drive is a south-to-north road; they meet at a point just east of Waynesboro, at which point another road (the Blue Ridge Parkway, a scenic route) heads southwest. Close to this point, yet another road heads roughly south from the 64 and is the shortest route from there to Lynchburg. Which of the two southish-pointing roads is meant isn't clear, but here they are on a map:

[image: map]

The description of the wayside turn-around sounds more fitted to a scenic route like the Blue Ridge Parkway, and indeed a later quote in the book reads:

> *The two lane highway wound steadily upward into the Blue Ridge*

So it looks as though the author does mean the Blue Ridge Parkway. Never mind the references to Lynchburg and the Skyline Drive; they're just confusing.

> Twenty miles in, he would come upon

It seems we have a slight authorial error here and this should be twenty *minutes*. Again picking a quote from slightly later in the book:

> *Twenty minutes later, he caught sight of the turn-around with its green sign stenciled with the number 13*

You can't drive at 60 mph along a road like the Blue Ridge Parkway, so twenty miles and twenty minutes can't both be right. Twenty minutes would also fit with the number "13" being a reference to the 13th milestone along the road; 40 mph sounds much more reasonable, and at that speed you would cover 13 miles in twenty minutes. So let's follow the Blue Ridge Parkway for 13 miles:

[image: map BRP]

> a wayside turn-around on a promontory overlooking a stretch of mountains and valleys within the George Washington National Forest. It would be marked with a small green sign with the number 13 in black. There would be a courtesy phone and a weather shelter.

The green milepost signs have now been replaced by stone markers; here's the 13th one:

[image: milestone]

Just a little further along the road, we arrive at this little wayside turn-around:

[image: turn-around]

Which is more or less as described. [This page](http://www.virtualblueridge.com/parkway-places/overlooks/) lists the 'overlooks' all along Blue Ridge Parkway; the one we've found is [Three Ridges Overlook](http://www.virtualblueridge.com/parkway-place/three-ridges-overlook/), at 13.1 miles from the start of the Parkway.

> He was to pull over, park, and lock the car with the keys inside, and cross the roadway to the nature path on the opposite side.

Here's the start of the nature path on the opposite side of the road:

[image: path]

Dun dun dunnnn.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for checking this out! Too bad there wasn't anything of note, alas. Looking at Google Maps, I do see one other option - the Blue Ridge Parkway that parallels 151 several miles to the west, but I'm over my lunch time & don't have time to look.

Comment: @RobertF Ah, I'd missed that one. It's probably not signposted to Lynchburg, but I'll investigate that road too and edit to post my findings. The reference to the Skyline Drive is also a bit confusing, since that comes in from the *north* and the quote says he's travelling west. Could you add a little more context to say where he travelled *from*?

Comment: Good point. Hmm, maybe Terry Brooks confused the Skyline Drive with the Blue Ridge Parkway? The character first flies to Charlottesville, then drives west on 64 towards Waynesboro before turning south.

Comment: @RobertF Edited - phew, that was a lot of work! :-) The Blue Ridge Parkway is closed for part of the year - I don't suppose the events in the book take place in winter by any chance?

Comment: @randal'thor Shortly after the OPs quote in the book (from my copy) is the following: “The two lane highway wound steadily upward into the Blue Ridge…” This is followed by, “Twenty minutes later, he caught sight of the turn-around with its green sign stenciled with the number 13…” 20 minutes later means less than 20 miles on those mountain roads and that sign is most likely a mile marker, which are on that road and have now been replaced with nice stone versions. If you go 13 miles down Blue Ridge, you will see the stone “13” followed by the turn around and a small booth.

Comment: @randal'thor The spot I mentioned is just northwest of Fenton Inn, and the mile marker is on the left if you go just north of the turn-around.

Comment: @S.Fruggiero Ugh, damn. Maybe "twenty miles" in the OP's quote was just a typo for "twenty minutes"? I think I've found the place you mean ([Three Ridges Overlook](http://www.virtualblueridge.com/parkway-place/three-ridges-overlook/)), and even the "nature path on the opposite side" - will you post an answer about it, or should I edit my answer crediting you?

Comment: @randal'thor Feel free to just add information to yours. For the record, 20 miles was not a typo on the OPs part, it says that in my book as well, but it also says "20 minutes" later on. So maybe just a small mistake on the author.

Comment: @RobertF Please see edited answer: S. Fruggiero has helped me find the place! If you go there, do let us know whether you find the portal :-)

Comment: This is really cool, wow! Thank you randal'thor and S.Fruggiero. It all checks out. Last night I poked around farther down the Blue Ridge Pkwy and found another turn-around & nature trail, but the closest mile marker didn't match (it was 23, not 13). It turns out Terry Brooks attended law school at Washington and Lee University in nearby Lexington, VI in the 1960s - wonder if he hiked down the trail at this very spot? Yes, next step is to hike 2 miles down the trail. Maybe Terry Brooks fans have decorated the spot. At the very least the film adaptation of the book ought to be filmed here.

Comment: @S.Fruggiero Expect a bounty in the next couple of days as thanks for your help with this answer :-)

Comment: Blue Ridge Parkway is not ALWAYS closed.  Sometimes snow can close it, but we don't often get that much snow.  Also, side point, BRP is free, SD costs, so I think most people know BRP better than SD.  I haven't driven SD in a while, but I don't remember it being nearly as winding as BRP.  Also, there are a number of scenic views on BRP that could be called "turn arounds."  I have driven through this spot many, many times.

Comment: FYI, you wouldn't say "the 64." 64 is short for "Interstate 64." Sometimes, it's rendered as I-64. It's just the name of the road.

Comment: FWIW, even 40 mph is too fast for some sections of the Parkway, unless you've got a death wish and are driving a road racing motorcycle...

Comment: @jpmc26, "The <interstate number>" is a very California way of saying it. Everyone else in the country just says "64" or "I-64", but hey, they from CA, gotta be different... :) (That was one of the first things I noticed as I read this answer, too.)

Comment: @FreeMan FWIW I've never even been to America. I just say it like I see it: the label on Google Maps (which I was using to plot out this answer) was "64", so I called it the 64.

Comment: Since you're not from CA, @Randal'Thor, you are forgiven for using "the 64". ;) As noted, referring to highways (of all sorts) by "the ___" is very common in California, but not the rest of the US. It's a minor nit pic on an otherwise excellent answer.

Comment: @Randal'Thor The little blue shield symbol with red trim behind the number tells you it's an interstate. These are major highways for distance traveling at high speeds. I-64 happens to go from the east coast all the way to Missouri.

Answer (score 2):

Confirmed by Terry Brooks?... I went to the "13" marker and tweeted this (and Terry Brooks re-tweeted my post):
"If you read @TerryBrooks 'Magic Kingdom For Sale/Sold' you know exactly where on the AT I am..."
https://x.com/kfranken42/status/1657904633614925828

[image]

Comment: Please quote the tweets and screenshot them, in case X gets rebranded back to Twitter or something else happens and the link breaks.