# Fantasy book where a normal man accepts job advertisement to become a king of a fantasy kingdom

Tags: story-identification, books

I read the first chapter of this book while I was waiting at a train station. I read it like a couple of years ago but I think that at least 3 books of the series were published so I'm not sure when the first edition dates back. It should be a series of 3-5 books. I live in Italy so the cover probably is different from other countries as they usually do here.

The protagonist is a normal person of our world who responds to a job advertisement in the newspaper, only that the job in question is to become king of a fantasy kingdom.

After responding to the announcement he finds himself in this new world where he is told that he has 30 days to decide whether to be crowned and stay there forever or return to our world. The court magician mistakenly puts him under a sleeping spell, and in those 30 days, he passes like 27/28 asleep. Obviously, in the end, he decided to be crowned.

Comment: You said it in a few places but I assume you meant him, if this wasn't correct you can [edit] your post to correct it.

Comment: Great book, great series

Comment: Just curious....does he decide to be crowned by the end of the first chapter? Is knowing this a spoiler?

Comment: @Fishcake No he doesn't in the first chapter, it takes the entire course of the book to convince him (and enable him to keep the throne). It's kind of a spoiler, but a pretty obvious one based on the book's premise (and the fact that there are lots of sequels).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Terry Brooks's *[Magic Kingdom for Sale -- Sold](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_Kingdom_for_Sale%E2%80%93Sold!)*.

[image: Classic Cover of *Magic Kingdon for Sale -- Sold*] [image: Italian cover of *Magic Kingdon for Sale -- Sold*] [image: 1991 Cover of *Magic Kingdon for Sale -- Sold*]

> The novel begins with Ben Holiday, a trial lawyer from Chicago, lamenting the loss of his wife and unborn child in a car accident. He finds an advertisement in an upscale Christmas catalog claiming to offer a magical kingdom for one million dollars by a man named Mr. Meeks. Although skeptical, Ben pursues the offer out of a desperate need to start a new life.
>
> Ben receives a magical medallion and is transported through a swirling mist to the kingdom of Landover. He learns that Landover is a world that connects many other worlds such as Earth. It is surrounded by the Fairy Mist wherein reside creatures of Fairy that created Landover and guard the passages to these worlds. Unfortunately, he finds it not exactly as described. He soon finds that Landover has not had a true king in twenty years. The son of the last king did not wish to take up the throne and escaped with the court wizard, Meeks, to Earth. They have been selling the throne to dozens of people in the past two decades, but no one has been able to face the challenge and successfully complete so much as a few months as king. Further, kings of Landover used to be protected by a magical knight called the Paladin, but he has not been seen since the last king's death.

It is a series. NeoDarwin was kind enough to provide a quote for the sleeping potion:

> "How could I have slept for a week?" he asked finally. Questor steepled his hands before his face. "Do you re-member the wine that you drank—the wine I provided?" Ben nodded. "Well, I added a dash of sleeping tonic to its content so that you would be assured of a good night's rest."He gestured with his hands. "It was in the magic I used, just an inflection of the voice and a twist." He demonstrated. "The trouble was, I overdid it. The dash became a thimbleful. So you have been asleep for a week." "Just a little mistake of the magic, is that it?" Ben was flushed with anger.

Comment: It's a sleeping spell so I think that it's an exact match

Comment: To date, there are 6 novels in the series. Five came out in the 1980s and 1990s (*Magic Kindom For Sale -- SOLD!*, *The Black Unicorn*, *Wizard at Large*, *The Tangle Box*, and *Witches' Brew*). A sixth book was released in 2009 (*A Princess of Landover*), starring the child of the original protagonist. Terry Brooks has apparently said there will be a seventh and final book, expected to be released in 2021.

Comment: For a while I thought we'd be seeing a film adaptation of this book, with Steve Carell playing Ben Holiday, but hasn't happened yet.

Comment: Also check out here - Rand al'Thor and S.Fruggiero found the actual location of the mile marker on the Blue Ridge Parkway where Ben Holiday enters Landover. :-) https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105430/was-the-location-of-the-portal-to-landover-in-magic-kingdom-for-sale-sold-a

Comment: Glad I could help. I enjoyed the series myself.